# Utilizing scipy.optimize.minimize properly

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have 2 fixed parameters `(A,B)` and 2 not-fixed parameters `(C,T_o)` used to calculate a computed Response value in the equation `R_computed = A + B*tanh((T-T_o)/C)`. The actual values "R" that it is being compared to needs to have a minimum possible error between the two. I have calculated the minimum error with a function that does a square root of the sum of the squares.

The function is what I am trying to minimize in the `optimize.minimize` with `C,T_o` being the `x0` and `args= (A,B,R,T)`.

**At the moment I am getting an error on line 52:**  `R_comp = A + B*np.tanh((T-T_o)/C)`

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

This error is new, I got past this before but can not go back to where I was as I have messed with the code too much. The end goal is to plot `(T,R)` and `(T,R_new)` where R_new would basically be a curve fit for R

Anything commented out is something I have tried.

```py
import numpy as np
#import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import scipy

import csv
import pandas as pd
#import operator

df =pd.DataFrame.from_csv('test.csv', index_col = None)
counter = 0
upper = 0
Lower_shelf = 2.2;
#import csv

with open('test.csv') as fin:
    csvin = csv.reader(fin, skipinitialspace=True)
    col_header = next(csvin, [])[1:]
    row_header, data = zip(*((row[0], row[1:]) for row in csvin))
    for row in data:
        if int(row[2]) >= 95 :
            upper = upper + float(row[0])
            counter = counter + 1
Upper_shelf = upper/counter
A = 33.18
B = 30.98      
T = array([  67.4,  100.7,  125.1,  150.6,  175.6,  200.3,  224.9,  249.8,
        275. ,  300. ,  350.5,  399.9,  425. ,  450.2,  475. ])
R = array([  6. ,  15.5,  20. ,  22. ,  30.5,  34. ,  45. ,  57. ,  54. ,
        63. ,  59. ,  64. ,  66. ,  64. ,  69. ])
T_o = (Tmax + Tmin)/2
C = (Tmax -T_o)/2


def ssre (A,B,T,R,C):
    R_comp = A + B*np.tanh((T-T_o)/C)

    ret_val = np.sqrt((R-R_comp)**2)
    return ret_val

Result = scipy.optimize.minimize(fun = ssre,x0 =[C,T_o], args= (A, B, R,T))
C_new = Result.x[0]
T_new = Result.x[1]
R_new = A + B*np.tanh((T-T_new)/C_new)
print(Result)
plt.plot(T,R, 'o')
plt.plot(T,R_new)
```

Comment: please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It would be useful to include the imports and initialize your variables (for example `A, B, R, T`) so we can have an idea about the shapes of these. This is essential for your type of error.

Comment: That is good and all, but without the right initializations, we can only guess.  In this version and since we don't have the `.csv` file, we still have no clue on `A, B, R, T`.

Comment: added more. the data is 4 columns and 15 rows in an excel file

Comment: A becomes one number; in this case A = 33.2, and B = 31

Comment: T = array([  67.4,  100.7,  125.1,  150.6,  175.6,  200.3,  224.9,  249.8,
        275. ,  300. ,  350.5,  399.9,  425. ,  450.2,  475. ])

Comment: R = array([  6. ,  15.5,  20. ,  22. ,  30.5,  34. ,  45. ,  57. ,  54. ,
        63. ,  59. ,  64. ,  66. ,  64. ,  69. ])

Comment: Does that help?

Comment: That is exactly what I am pointing out.  Edit your code and use the last 3 comments to initialize your variables in the code and make sure it compiles.

Comment: That will definitely guarantee you more attention and consequently an answer.

Comment: I think I understand what you are going for, I have edited more

Answer (score 0):

It was a bit tricky to sort this out, since despite the edits the code still included various problems. As an advise for future posts, please try to post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to make it easier for other users to understand your code and goals. Consequently you will get fast and good quality answers.

Concerning your code, I corrected the following:

- correct the ssre function call the way you pass variables to it.
- correct the computations of the square root of the sum of the square which is equal to the l2-norm.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from scipy.optimize import minimize


def ssre (x, A, B, R, T):
    C, T_o  = x[0], x[1]
    R_comp  = A + B*np.tanh((T - T_o) / C)
    ret_val = np.linalg.norm(R - R_comp, 2)
    return ret_val

# initializations 
A   = 33.2
B   = 31
T   = np.array([67.4, 100.7, 125.1, 150.6, 175.6, 200.3, 224.9, 249.8, 275., 300., 350.5, 399.9, 425., 450.2, 475.])
R   = np.array([  6.,  15.5,   20.,   22.,  30.5,   34.,   45.,   57.,  54.,  63.,   59.,   64.,  66.,   64.,  69.])
T_o = (np.max(T) + np.min(T))/2
C   = (np.max(T) - T_o)/2

# minimize
Result = minimize(fun  = ssre,
                  x0   = [C, T_o],
                  args = (A, B, R, T))
# format results
C_new = Result.x[0]
T_new = Result.x[1]
R_new = A + B*np.tanh((T-T_new)/C_new)

# print and plot
print(Result)
plt.plot(T, R, 'o')
plt.plot(T, R_new)
plt.show()
```

Result:

```
      fun: 11.786475736024007
 hess_inv: array([[84.27271526, -4.45138785],
       [-4.45138785, 23.62509084]])
      jac: array([1.78813934e-06, 9.53674316e-07])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nfev: 76
      nit: 14
     njev: 19
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([ 98.74898359, 182.5084917 ])
```

[image]

- consider taking a look at [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) as an alternative approach.